# Tidy HTML5 & PHP7

Tags: html, ubuntu, tidy

So I am on an Ubuntu server at Digital Ocean and I'm trying to install/configure Tidy HTML5 with my current PHP7 Wordpress installation and W3 Total Cache.

However even though I've installed Tidy with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove libtidy-0.99-0 tidy -y
sudo wget -O /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb http://binaries.html-tidy.org/binaries/tidy-5.2.0/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb

sudo dpkg -i /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb

sudo rm /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb
```

And it even says that it is at Version 5.2.0, yet it doesn't seem to be loaded/installed.

```
rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-recode.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ tidy -v
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.2.0
```

Am I missing something here? Or doesn't HTML Tidy work with PHP7? Because I've installed HTML Tidy with the above mentioned commands without any problem on a PHP5.6 installation just fine recently.

Either way thanks for any suggestions or information.

Edit:

I've removed Tidy completely, installed the original from 2009, still not detected, then removed it again and installed the latest version again but yet again it's still not being detected:

```
rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo apt-get install tidy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
tidy is already the newest version (20091223cvs-1.5).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tidy : Depends: libtidy-0.99-0 (>= 20091223cvs-1.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libtidy-0.99-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtidy-0.99-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 419 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 120416 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtidy-0.99-0_20091223cvs-1.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtidy-0.99-0 (20091223cvs-1.5) ...
Setting up libtidy-0.99-0 (20091223cvs-1.5) ...
Setting up tidy (20091223cvs-1.5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...


rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo apt-get -y autoremove tidy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libtidy-0.99-0 tidy
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
After this operation, 505 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 120421 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tidy (20091223cvs-1.5) ...
Removing libtidy-0.99-0 (20091223cvs-1.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo wget -O /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb http://binaries.html-tidy.org/binaries/tidy-5.2.0/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb
--2017-02-22 20:15:50--  http://binaries.html-tidy.org/binaries/tidy-5.2.0/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb
Resolving binaries.html-tidy.org (binaries.html-tidy.org)... 151.101.64.133, 151.101.128.133, 151.101.192.133, ...
Connecting to binaries.html-tidy.org (binaries.html-tidy.org)|151.101.64.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 727594 (711K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb’

/tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb     100%[==============================================>] 710.54K  --.-KB/s    in 0.007s

2017-02-22 20:15:50 (100 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb’ saved [727594/727594]

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb
Selecting previously unselected package tidy.
(Reading database ... 120410 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb ...
Unpacking tidy (5.2.0) ...
Setting up tidy (5.2.0) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo rm /tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb

rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ tidy -v
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.2.0
rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Am I really missing something here?

Comment: Ah yes that was an incorrect command I've entered to call tidy, I've edited my main message as that was irrelevant. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: `tidy -v` returns `HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.2.0` . Given that you installed `/tmp/tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb` this seems right to me. What am I missing? ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Indeed I've got no clue what the actual problem is, as just requesting the version gets me:


    rafael@wordpress-staging:~$ tidy -v
    HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.2.0

Back, so I got no clue why I can't actually use it either oO?

Comment: ah, sorry, not really a php person, so the problem is that `tidy` is not listed in the plugins. Doah... Do `which tidy`? You'll get back something like `/usr/local/bin/tidy` . Make sure the directory portion of that path (`/usr/local/bin` (or similar) )  is in your php config (I don't know where to put it). I wouldn't expect `tidy` install to know  or worry about php specifics, so you'll have to nose around either in `tidy` or `php` specific forums to figure out how to connect the two. . . . .

Comment: Your Q reads more like "My tidy install isn't working" rather than "Why can't php find tidy". There are so many php Qs, you may wait a while before someone looking for reputation points finds your unanswered Q. You might consider deleting this one and reposting with a stronger problem description. All of the Install info is irrelevant, because you can show that `tidy -v` produces the right output.. Good luck!